# unable to modify config files in cloudera Hadoop 4.7 distribution

Tags: linux, file-permissions, cloudera, permission-denied, user-permissions

I was trying to add more properties on hdfs-site.xml , mapred-site.xml , core-site.xml and flume-ng/sample-agent.conf files but. I get message as I don't have privileges to modify the files. But i have logged in using root user cloudera.

i user command as `vi <filename>` and add properties which ever is required but when i try to save it get above message. I tried to edit using tool gedit also but it also showed me same message.

Please someone guide me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: use sudo vi file_name

Comment: I had tried this but still iam unable to modify the files.

Comment: try ls -al and show the result

Comment: Seems that is not the root user. Try sudo su , now you will become root, Now try to modify the file.

Comment: @AmalGJose Thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iam able to edit the files by login to root user and command here is `SU -`